# Main menu not showing on cck type content items

Tags: routes, entities, 7

I have that annoying issue with my main menu not showing on nodes of one specific cck content type. The menu shows everywhere else and is set to do so in the block settings by using the [Menu Block](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_block) module.

I just don't get why it's behaving like this. Display of the node is done by using views & context / nothing special in the end. All fields which are visible are generated through views (in content type display settings, all are set 'hidden' - changing this, doesn't help).

Displaying the `$page` variable, the menu's aren't there, too. So which function should I have a closer look on for debugging?

The menu settings allow display everywhere (no restrictions), cache is disabled in the browser / doing drush cc often.

I'm accessing with user 1. (system is D7)

Answer (score 0):

Issue was that the url patterns changed and I still had some old items - so for these the menu didn't display. Don't know why, but updating all content items of that type with the new url pattern solved the issue.